# Точка после запятой не нужна

Tags: дефект, локализация

> Учётная запись временно заблокирована,. Дата окончания блокировки: 13 июл в 18:31.

[image: скриншот]

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/176051/squidward

Comment: там скорее всего иногда что-то дописывается, например причину

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, значит в этом придатке и надо дописывать.

Comment: @Aid угу ......

Comment: @alexolut, а править-то будем?

Comment: @Qwertiy будем. Но хотелось бы участия участников сначала. А раз нет, то я могу и свою линию выгнуть, может кому не понравится потом :)

Comment: @Qwertiy исправили и красную метки повесили. Можете принимать дубликат :)